# Ajax Long Polling Restrictions

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache, long-polling

So a friend and I are building a web based, AJAX chat software with a jQuery and PHP core. Up to now, we've been using the standard procedure of calling the sever every two seconds or so looking for updates. However I've come to dislike this method as it's not fast, nor is it "cost effective" in that there are tons of requests going back and forth from the server, even if no data is returned.

One of our project supporters recommended we look into a technique known as COMET, or more specifically, Long Polling. However after reading about it in different articles and blog posts, I've found that it isn't all that practical when used with Apache servers. It seems that most people just say "It isn't a good idea", but don't give much in the way of specifics in the way of how many requests can Apache handle at one time.

The whole purpose of PureChat is to provide people with a chat that looks great, goes fast, and works on most servers. As such, I'm assuming that about 96% of our users will being using Apache, and not Lighttpd or Nginx, which are supposedly more suited for long polling.

**Getting to the Point:**

In your opinion, is it better to continue using setInterval and repeatedly request new data? Or is it better to go with Long Polling, despite the fact that most users will be using Apache? Also, it possible to get a more specific rundown on approximately how many people can be using the chat before an Apache server rolls over and dies?

Comment: Tomcat 7 latest added support for WebSockets, so consider that with a polling fallback as another alternative.

Comment: If this is small scale, it shoudln't be an issue. If you are planning on 1000s of concurrent users, Apache will die, because for each connection, it opens a new thread, which costs a good amount of memory. NginX runs on a single thread, so it can scale to many connections. If you are using PHP however, this will not help you as much as you think in many cases. See my below answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Andrew stated, a socket connection is the ultimate solution for asynchronous communication with a server, although only the most cutting edge browsers support WebSockets at this point. socket.io is an open source API you can use which will initiate a WebSocket connection if the browser supports it, but will fall back to a Flash alternative if the browser does not support it. This would be transparent to the coder using the API however.

Socket connections basically keep open communication between the browser and the server so that each can send messages to each other at any time. The socket server daemon would keep a list of connected subscribers, and when it receives a message from one of the subscribers, it can immediately send this message back out to all of the subscribers.

For socket connections however, you need a socket server daemon running full time on your server. While this can be done with command line PHP (no Apache needed), it is better suited for something like node.js, a non-blocking server-side JavaScript api.

node.js would also be better for what you are talking about, long polling. Basically node.js is event driven and single threaded. This means you can keep many connections open without having to open as many threads, which would eat up tons of memory (Apaches problem). This allows for high availability. What you have to keep in mind however is that even if you were using a non-blocking file server like Nginx, PHP has many blocking network calls. Since It is running on a single thread, each (for instance) MySQL call would basically halt the server until a response for that MySQL call is returned. Nothing else would get done while this is happening, making your non-blocking server useless. If however you used a non-blocking language like JavaScript (node.js) for your network calls, this would not be an issue. Instead of waiting for a response from MySQL, it would set a handler function to handle the response whenever it becomes available, allowing the server to handle other requests while it is waiting.

For long polling, you would basically send a request, the server would wait 50 seconds before responding. It will respond sooner than 50 seconds if it has anything to report, otherwise it waits. If there is nothing to report after 50 seconds, it sends a response anyways so that the browser does not time out. The response would trigger the browser to send another request, and the process starts over again. This allows for fewer requests and snappier responses, but again, not as good as a socket connection.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that socket server daemons require access to your server's sockets, which would typically not be allowed on a shared server. You would need a VPS.

Comment: Thanks you for your detailed response. It's much appreciated. The problem I'm essentially faced with here, is that since we are releasing the chat as an open source software, we aren't in control of the servers it would be installed on. In light of that, we have to assume that a large majority of users will be on shared hosting. So, they will probably not have access to sockets, nor will they likely have Node.js installed. Do you think it would be better for us to implement Long Polling with a user limit/cap, so things don't get out of hand?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not quite sure. As you say, different servers have different amounts of memory. I did a quick google search for PHP functions that return the amount of memory left. All I got were functions that returned the amount of memory used.

Comment: Any alternative for websockets?